# Mysql case statements with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, case

I am writing a query to gather data on survey responses.  Users tick on a box, which then generates a 0 if not ticked and a 1 if ticked.   This is for a survey to measure outcomes for hip joint replacements (arthoplasties)

I want to identify those records where patients have not seen any of the clinician types identified in the survey.  If none of these were seen, then the response should be a score of 0.

So, I tried writing a case statement as follows:

```
CASE
WHEN o_hip_arthroplasty_first.health_educator = 0 AND
  o_hip_arthroplasty_first.rheumatologist = 0 AND
  o_hip_arthroplasty_first.general_practitioner = 0 AND
  o_hip_arthroplasty_first.orthopaedic_surgeon = 0 AND
  o_hip_arhtroplasty_first.alternative_health_practitioner = 0 THEN 0
END AS TREATMENT_PROVIDER_NONE,
```

Unfortunately, this fails. When using MySQL Workbench, I don't get a specific error here--just what looks to be a repeat of the query in the error window.  I know this is the problem because the query runs when I comment it out.

Simpler case statements work without problem, such as:

```
CASE
WHEN o_hip_arthroplasty_first.health_educator = 1 then 1
END AS TREATMENT_PROVIDER_HEALTH_EDUCATOR,
```

and even other conditional case statements are working:

```
CASE 
WHEN o_hip_arthroplasty_first.PATIENT_LEFTKNEEJOINT = 1 OR
o_hip_arthroplasty_first.PATIENT_LEFTKNEEOST = 1 OR
o_hip_arthroplasty_first.PATIENT_LEFTKNEELIG = 1 OR
o_hip_arthroplasty_first.PATIENT_LEFTKNEEOTHER = 1 then 4
END AS SURG_HIS_LT_KNEE,
```

I cannot understand why the statement with multiple 'AND' conditionals is not working.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to amend this?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Tony

Comment: This schema might be an issue. A proper relational one might be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Your `CASE` *expression* (not "statement") seems valid... but somewhat pointless or incomplete -- it can only ever evaluate to 0 or `NULL`.

Comment: I started again with the expression, one line at a time, and managed to get it to work.  I'm not quite sure the difference but below was the code that worked:  CASE WHEN o_hip_arthroplasty_first.alternative_health_practitioner  = 0
AND o_hip_arthroplasty_first.general_practitioner = 0 
AND o_hip_arthroplasty_first.rheumatologist = 0
AND o_hip_arthroplasty_first.health_educator = 0
AND o_hip_arthroplasty_first.orthopaedic_surgeon = 0
then 0
END AS TREATMENT_PROVIDER_NONE

from o_hip_arthroplasty_first

Comment: The expression I used is a part of a bigger query (which is why it didn't make much sense on its own).  This was the first step--to say a patient hadn't seen any of these professionals.  There are other case statements to confirm whether they saw any one (or more) of them.  

Thank you all for your help!